# How to save a string into file in applicationdirectory and get its real location? (Adobe Air)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, file, air

How to save a string into file (`file.superlongextention`) in `applicationdirectory` and get its real locationon Hard drive (like `C:/files/...`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reason you can't write into the [Application directory](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationDirectory) (for testing you can but it 's realy not recommended).

You can write into the Application Storage directory to store your application data.

- Use [File](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/File.html) then [FileStream](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) to write your data.
- To get the path of the file use [nativePath](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/File.html#nativePath).

  ```
  import flash.filesystem.File;
  import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
  import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
  import mx.controls.Alert;

  // get a file reference to the storage directory
  var file:File=File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myfile.withextension");

  // create a file stream
  var fs:FileStream=new FileStream();

  // open the stream for writting
  fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

  // write the string data down to the file
  fs.writeUTFBytes("my string to save");

  // ok close the file stream
  fs.close();

  // show the path to the file we have saved using Alert
  Alert.show(file.nativePath);
  ```

Comment: Hm... I use Flash builder 4. I wrapped your code (not imports ofcourse) into public function. But when I try to run it it gives me SecurityError: fileWriteResource
 at flash.filesystem::FileStream/open()

Comment: So I changed applicationDirectory to userDirectory and it now works...)

Comment: But how to get rid of "0" in the begining of line?

Comment: Yes sorry as i said you can't write to applicationDirectory, and i left it in the code, my bad. It 's applicationStorageDirectory in my code. writeUTF write also the length of the string so use writeUTFBytes instead. I have modified the code.

Answer (score 1):

but you can save file in Applicationdirectory

```
var appPath:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("");
var fromUserPath:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(appPath.nativePath);
```

Thanks to Tanel Teemusk

http://blog.teemusk.com/2011/10/writing-to-applicationdirectory-with-adobe-air/